# makeinfo is not found, although installed. How can I fix this problem?

Tags: gcc

I'm just building an GCC version from source.

During the make step, I get the error message

```
"WARNING: `makeinfo' is missing on your system. You should only need it if you modified a `texi' or a
`.texinfo' file, or any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual. The spurious call might also be the consequence of using a buggy
`make' (AIX, DU, IRIX). You might want to install the `Texinfo' package or the `GNU make' package. Grab either from any GNU archive site."
```

texinfo was already installed with the command `sudo apt install texinfo`.

What can I do about the problem?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Did you install `texinfo` before you started trying to build GCC, or did you encounter this build error and then install it?

Comment: Thank you very much. 

I installed `texinfo` after encountering the build error.

Comment: Then the likely cause is that your autotools build configuration cache is out
of date. It checked for an installed `texinfo` when
you ran `./configure ...`, stored answer "missing" and was not rerun from
clean after your installed `texinfo`. Run `make distclean` in the
build directory; then start again from `./configure...`.

Comment: Try adding this bit to the configure-invocation: `./configure ... MAKEINFO=$(which makeinfo)`